# Applying knockout validation to an object

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I have been trying to wrap my head around how I am supposed to apply knockout validation to my view model.  In all of the examples I have found, validation is being applied to individual properties in the view model.  However I was wondering if it is possible to apply validation to individual properties in a java script object?  Here is my view model code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindViewModel();
});

function ManageCustomerViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.searchResults = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
    self.customerCount = ko.observable();
    self.Customer = ko.observable();
    self.SearchOnKey = function (data, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 9) {
            self.CustomerSearch(data);
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    };

    self.AddCustomer = function () {

         var cust =  {
            Id: 0,
            FirstName: "",
            LastName: "",
            EmailAddress: "",
            AlternatePhone: "",
            BillingAddress: "",
            BillingCity: "",
            BillingState: "",
            BillingZip: "",
            PrimaryPhone: "",
            ShippingAddress: "",
            ShippingCity: "",
            ShippingState: "",
            ShippingZip: ""
         }
         self.Customer(cust);
    };

    self.UpdateCustomer = function () {
        ShowLoading();
        if (self.Customer().Id > 0) {
            $.ajax("../api/CustomerAPI/UpdateCustomer", {
                data: ko.mapping.toJSON(self.Customer),
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (e) {
                    HideLoading();
                    $('#Modal').modal('hide');
                }
            }).fail(function () { HideLoading() });
        }
        else {
            $.ajax("../api/CustomerAPI/InsertNewCustomer", {
                data: ko.mapping.toJSON(self.Customer),
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (e) {
                    HideLoading();
                    $('#Modal').modal('hide');
                }
            }).fail(function () { HideLoading() });
        }
    };

    self.GetCustomerDetails = function (c) {
        ShowLoading();
        $.getJSON("../api/CustomerAPI/GetCustomerByID", { id: c.Id }, function (cust) {
            self.Customer(cust);
            HideLoading();
        }).fail(function () { HideLoading() });
    }

    self.CustomerSearch = function (data) {

        var first = $("#txtFirstName").val();
        var last = $("#txtLastName").val();
        var email = $("#txtEmail").val();

        first = first.trim();
        last = last.trim();
        email = email.trim();

        if (first == "" && last == "" & email == "") {
            alert("Please enter at least one search value");
        }
        else {
            ShowLoading();
            $.getJSON("../api/CustomerAPI/GetCustomerSearchResults", { lastname: last, firstname: first, email: email }, function (allData) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(allData, self.searchResults);
                self.customerCount(self.searchResults().length);
                HideLoading();
            }).fail(function () { HideLoading() });
        }
    };
}

function BindViewModel() {

    ko.applyBindings(new ManageCustomerViewModel());
};
```

As you can see, I am using the Customer object to pass data back and forth.  I would like to add validation to the properties of Customer.  Is this doable or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: You can assign validation to individual observables in an object

Comment: If you have a working solution and are solliciting feedback on how to improve the code, you may be interested in [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (be sure to read their FAQ though).

Comment: You can not add validation to properties that are not knokcout observables. The ko.validation method 'extend' can only be chained with an observable.

Comment: @WayneEllery Could you provide an example?

Comment: just try like this a fiddle from one of my posts http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/93/